# gdm3 switching keyboard input method does not take effect

Tags: 22.04, input-method

We recently upgraded our Ubuntu box to Jammy 22.04 LTS. Since its lightdm cannot work at all (screen hangs after start, no mouse, cannot type anything from keyboard), we switched to gdm3.

But after gdm3 login, we found that we cannot switch the input methods between normal English or Chinese Bopomofo. In the upper-right corner, we can use mouse to switch between English and Chinese input methods, but it does not take effect in the applications (like browser, terminal, ... etc). In all the applications they are still stick in English input.

Could anyone help us to solve this problem ? Thank you very much.

Cheers,
T.H.Hsieh

Answer (score 0):

After many trials and errors, we finally assumed that the ibus-bopomofo Chinese input method may have bug (for Ubuntu Jammy 22.04 LTS system). Therefore, we solved this problem by the following steps:

1. Edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf, to force the login screen using Xorg:

```
   WaylandEnable=false
```

2. Install ibus-chewing Chinese input method to replace the ibus-bopomofo input method:

```
   apt install ibus-chewing
```

3. Reboot the system. Then one can select ibus-chewing input method from Preference / Keyboard.